# Why is data from Arduino to Android using Android host api garbled?

Tags: android, arduino

I followed [this](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549) tutorial to get started using Android host api with an Arduino board.  I am using the Arduino Uno.  I am able to transmit data and turn on a LED on the Arduino board and I can receive feedback from the Arduino board.  I am trying to write to my Android device over the USB connection from the Arduino board like so:

```
 Serial.print("Test");
```

I am receiving the Arduino data on the Android side like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
int bytes;
//try-catch statements omitted for simplicity
bytes = mUsbConnection.bulkTransfer(mUsbEndpointIn, buffer, buffer.length, 0);
```

Every once and awhile the data will be intact but more often than not, what I receive from the Arduino is a garbled mix of those letters from my original message(t,e,s, and t).  Many times only 1 or 2 letters are displayed.  If anyone could point me in the right direction or share some similar experience I would be appreciative.  Thanks.

**Edit**

When I print out the data into Logcat, there are multiple copies of the data.  For example, if I receive "ste" from Arduino, it will be printed out 2-5 times in Logcat.

Comment: Are you setting a baud rate in your arduino script? The command would look something like this: Serial.begin(115200); You may have a different number. Post what number yours does have if it does. If you had it set incorrectly I think it would be possible for you to get the errors that you are seeing.

Comment: @Tim = I have set it at 9600 bps: Serial.begin(9600);  I realize it is quite low, do you think this could cause a problem?  I wonder how I would determine the frequency that is most optimized for Android.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what the faster / slower baud rate would effect. I think the most important is that both devices are expecting the same rate. Try setting the rate to each of the other values that show up in the arduino serial moniter dropdown box. Run each respectively and see if any of them make a difference with the string you are trying to send. I know 115200 is one of the other rates, but I don't recall the others that show up in that dropdown there are only a handful though to test.

Comment: @Tim = Great.  Thank you for the tip, I will try it out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something that works at least temporarily:

```
public void run(){

        int i = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[8];
        byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[8];

        int bytes = 0;

        while(true){
            try{

                bytes = mUsbConnection.bulkTransfer(mUsbEndpointIn, buffer, buffer.length, 0);

                if (bytes == EXIT_CMD) { 
                    return;
                } 

                if (bytes > 0){

                    byte[] temporaryBuffer = new byte[bytes];

                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, temporaryBuffer, 0, bytes);

                    System.arraycopy(temporaryBuffer, 0, finalBuffer, i, bytes);

                    i += bytes;

                    java.util.Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
                }

                //Dollar sign terminates string to indicate end of line
                if (finalBuffer[7] == 36){

                    i = 0;

                    System.arraycopy(finalBuffer, 0, sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.length); 

                    messageHandler.obtainMessage(UsbHostTestActivity.ARDUINO_MESSAGE, 
                            sendBuffer.length, -1, sendBuffer).sendToTarget();

                    java.util.Arrays.fill(finalBuffer, (byte) 0);
                }
```

I had to send strings that were 8 characters exactly from Arduino and they had to end with a dollar sign($) in order to indicate the end of the line, but the data being passed to my message handler always seemed to be correct.  It's not the most robust solution but maybe someone can modify it to make it better or take another approach? Please let me know!